# How can I extract a page from a PDF file?

Tags: perl, pdf

Is there any Perl script to get the pages from a PDF file and convert the same to another PDF file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked for Perl, so here's a good solution via [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?deletepdfpage.pl).  Say you just want pages 3-6 of orig.pdf to be saved to new.pdf:

```
deletepdfpage.pl orig.pdf 1-2,7- new.pdf
```

Answer (score 5):

[PdfTK](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/).

```
~$ pdftk multi-page.pdf burst
```

Answer (score 3):

As *gnud* already answered, [pdftk](http://www.pdftk.com/) is the best tool for the job. For example, to extract pages 5-10 from **test.pdf** to **out.pdf** you would write:

```
pdftk test.pdf cat 5-10 output out.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

On OS X you can just do this in Preview, by dragging pages in the thumbnail view.

Answer (score 1):

The code given by Andreas didn't work for me. If using [Pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/), on Windows this formula worked for me :

```
pdftk source.pdf cat 123-128 output out.pdf dont_ask
```

Source being obviously the source pdf, 123-128 the intervall of pages to extract and out.pdf the new pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in actual code...This code may be useful for you :

use CAM::PDF;

my $file_name="abc.pdf";

my $pdf = CAM::PDF ->new($file_name);
my $no_pages=$pdf->numPages();

for(my $i=1;$igetPageText($i);
    print "$page\n";
    # may u can read it an array/etc...manipulation can be done here
    }

Comment: Sorry, but I have to downvote this answer even though I'm the author of CAM::PDF. getPageText() is just about the worst possible way to approach this problem. Instead, try the extractPages() method in CAM::PDF or the deletepages.pl wrapper program that comes with the library.

Answer (score 0):

Interactively, there is the full version of Acrobat.  Programatically there is the [Acrobat SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/index.html?navID=downloads) from Adobe and lots of 3rd party solutions.  Google [Acrobat API](http://www.google.com/search?q=acrobat+api).