# Picking pages from PDF document

Tags: unix, pdf

**How can you pick pages from a PDF file?**

**Pseudo-code synopsis**

```
 pick-pages 1,2-69,70-73,100 example.pdf > put_to_new_file.pdf
```

Comment: At least it would have to be: pick-pages original.pdf 1,2-69,70-73,100 target.pdf

Comment: This has been covered before. More than once.

Comment: dmckee: Please, add links to the location where this has been discussed before.

Comment: In addition to questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730613/pdf-document-manipulation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416851/how-can-i-extract-a-page-from-a-pdf-file *I* gave *you* this information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757689/how-can-i-compile-first-2-pages-of-24-pages-in-a-latex-document/757768#757768 .

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. The worst answer being the accepted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're after `pdftk`.

Answer (score 4):

My best suggestion would be to try something with [PDF toolkit](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) - with Split and Merge, and a simple .bat file construction, something like that shouldn't be much hard.

Answer (score 2):

ghostscript, somethign like

```
gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=3 -dLastPage=3 -sOutputFile=fileout.pdf filein.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've done it with regular expressions.  I counted the number of matches for the following regular expressions:

```
/Type\s*/Page[^s]
```

Case insensitive, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not a popular method, but this is one way. You can use pdflatex. For example, you can write a tex like:

```
\documentclass{book}\usepackage{pdfpages}\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={1,2-10,11}]{pdf.pdf}\end{document}
```

You can write a small script to automize this.

Comment: The best way is pdftk. The problem is installing pdftk from MacPorts requires to install a free JavaVM, which bugs me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As part of my CAM::PDF Perl library on CPAN, I bundle a command-line utility [deletepdfpage.pl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?deletepdfpage.pl) that does the inverse of what you are asking for, with almost the exact same syntax:

```
deletepdfpage.pl original.pdf 74-99,101- target.pdf
```